# PHP - Incorrect POST data being sent through a form upon echo?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, postdata

I'm writing a simple registration form to add users to a database. The code is below.

```
<?php
include 'header.php';
$tag = randomString();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Register an Account</title>
</head>
<body>
<b>Register an account</b><br><br>
<form method="post" action="add_user.php?tag=<?echo $tag;?>">
Username: <br><input type="text" name="username" size=25/><br /><br>
Password: <br><input type="password" name="password" size=25/><br /><br>
Confirm Password: <br><input type="password" name="confirm" size=25/><br /><br>
Email Address: <br><input type="text" name="email" size=25/><br /><br><br>
Additional Info: <br><input type="text" name="info" size=50/><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The form seems to work fine. However, when I attempt to read this post data on the next page, some entries are correct, and others are not, even when all entries are filled. For example:

```
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username'])); --> outputs what was in the info field
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['password'])); --> output is what was entered in "confirm"
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['confirm'])); --> no output
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['email'])); --> email is outputted, this is correct. 
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['info'])); --> No output.
```

Very confused as to why this is happening, I've written many forms with no such problems.

EDIT: Here's the var_dump (data entered: username, Pass1, Pass2, email@address.com, and info in the proper order):

```
array(4) { ["username"]=> string(4) "info" ["password"]=> string(5) "Pass2" ["email"]=> string(17)     "email@address.com" ["Submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" }
```

EDIT2: Added entire page's code

**add_user.php** (Not finished-- the issue came up when I was trying to compare the two passwords. That never evaluated as true, mainly because I wasn't comparing what I thought I was)

```
<?php
//var_dump($_POST);

echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['username'])); echo "<br>";
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['password'])); echo "<br>";
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['confirm'])); echo "<br>";
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['email'])); echo "<br>";
echo mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['info'])); echo "<br>";

if ($_POST['password'] != $_POST['confirm']) {
die("Passwords do not match. Please go back and try again.");
}
$tag = $_GET['tag'];
?>
```

Comment: What about a simple `var_dump($_POST)` for testing?

Comment: This is interesting. `mysql_real_escape_string` shouldn't output anything. Neither should `htmlentities`.

Comment: Added the var_dump. And just to clarify, those statements are all echoed, but when I pasted the code here, I forgot the echo statements.

Comment: Can you post the *complete* code? Maybe there is an error somewhere else?

Comment: Added entire code. It's very simple, which is why this is so confusing.

Comment: can you post add_user.php? also header.php

Comment: It is add_user.php doing the echo, no...?

Comment: Post add_user.php please

Comment: Added the two php files. @Smar I am echoing the data on add_user.php.

Comment: If the values aren't in `$_POST` then the problem is with the form HTML.

Comment: try using get and see what vars you get in the url

Comment: also try putting a default value field as value="" in each field

Comment: You could also try to use $_REQUEST

Comment: @Anush

GET url is
add_user.php?username=Username&password=pass&confirm=pass&email=email@email.com&info=www.google.com&Submit=Submit#a

Which looks perfect. Perhaps I should just use GET (although on a registration page, I don't particularly want to.)

Comment: Try doing post but this time instead of using $_POST, try $_REQUEST

Comment: @Anush That seems like it worked fine. Any idea why that would have worked over POST?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that $_POST is not values "confirm" and "info" at all. That’s why they don’t output anything.

I suggest to switch PHP’s notices on, they would tell this instantly.

I can’t think but that you have filled the form wrong. Since ”info” is value of “username”.