# Array sent from Android to PHP via $_POST getting mucked up in transit

Tags: php, android, arrays, post

This problem is driving me crazy and I have no idea how to fix it. I have an Android program to gather all names and phone numbers into an array (basic key-value pairs) and then send that array over to a PHP script. The PHP script then parses the values received in a $_POST and inserts them into a MySQL table. Everything works fine except that the data doesn't always come as posted. For instance, some numbers get paired with names they don't belong to. Here's a snippet of my PHP:

```
$ar = 0;
foreach($_POST as $entry){
    echo $ar.". ".$_POST[$ar]."\n";
    $namenum = explode(',', $entry);
    $names[$ar] = $namenum[1];
    $numbers[$ar] = $namenum[0];
    echo $ar.". ".$numbers[$ar]."--->".$names[$ar]."\n"; 
    $ar += 1;
}
$namenum = NULL;
//$ar = NULL;
```

The above snippet is right at the beginning of the script and there's nothing to tamper with $_POST. The echo within the loop is to test this exact thing and that's how I discovered the problem. The weirdest part is that most of the time, the data received is exactly as sent. But then at times I suddenly notice a couple of numbers getting either mixed up with wrong names or disappearing altogether. I must also add that each time I have tested the program, I've done it on the same device, using the same contact list. Everything remains the same between test runs and yet results vary at random. The gremlins seem to be appearing in transit! Is this a known issue with $_POST or sending arrays in general? If so, what alternatives do I have? I can think of JSON or text files but would that ensure better data fidelity?

**UPDATE 1:** Based on Anush' comment on [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880017/php-incorrect-post-data-being-sent-through-a-form-upon-echo?rq=1), I just tried using $_REQUEST but the problem persists.

**UPDATE 2:** Just tried adding a **var_dump($_POST)** right before the **foreach()** loop. Ran 5 tests with 4 returning accurate values and the last one mixing up 1 contact (number matched with the wrong name). As stated above, no variables were changed between tests, i.e. no changes to either the device phonebook or the Android/PHP code. All 5 tests ran within the same environment.

**UPDATE 3:** I stripped the PHP down to this:

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

Same results except that this time the gremlins showed up on the 3rd run instead of the 5th.

Comment: have you confirmed that the key value pairs are correct before they are sent to PHP?

Comment: Yes they're correct. As I said, nothing changes between subsequent tests and yet the results retrieved from $_POST changes. On the Android side, there's no change in the contact list, nor in the Android program. That's why am pulling my hair in frustration. :(

Comment: simplify everything as much as possible and use the simplest form of the program to debug, for example in PHP just do a `foreach as $key => $value` loop and do the same in your Android app before the values are sent, I doubt it's a problem with the language / method of transit. You may have an extra value posted to PHP such as a hidden field or submit button you're not noticing?

Comment: I'm already doing a foreach on $_POST. The snippet I posted with the question is the simplest I could manage. echo $ar.". ".$_POST[$ar]."\n"; is already there to show everything inside the array with each iteration of foreach. Did the same on Android side too and the problem still at least appears to be sporadic and in-flight.

Comment: try replacing the above code with `foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {echo $key . ' => ' . $value . '<br />'; }` and see if that reveals anything, just a suggestion really, it's what I would do first

Comment: OK just tried and yet no idea what's going wrong. Performed 3 runs of the program with 2 results showing accurate results and the 3rd one with 2 numbers mismatched. Do note that nothing was changed in the code or the phonebook in between the tests.

Comment: Try sending something hard-coded to PHP to confirm whether it receives it ok, just make another array with the same values and send that

Comment: Check how you are getting the names and phone numbers.  Most of the time the arrangement is not as you expect them..